# postgres jsonb array index

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have created a model in loopback with 3 properties connected to postgres. Among the properties defined, I have one array property.
My model is defined below.

**My model :**

```
{
    "name" : "Main",
    "base" : "PersistedModel",
    "properties" : {
        "cusId" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index : true
        },
        "fd2" : {
            "type" : "number"
        },
        "fd3" : {
            "type" : "number"
        },
        "test" : {
            "type": ["Test"]
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Model :**

```
{
    "name" : "Test",
    "base" : "PersistedModel",
    "properties" : {
        "productId" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "desc" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

In my main model - I have mentioned  cusId with index as true (this will automatically create the index in postgres). When I post the main model data, test is an array and will be stores as JSONB array. How to set the index of the JSONB array property[productId].